# OpenStreetMap Java load place on map

Tags: java, netbeans, openstreetmap, jxmapkit

As a newbie I'm making a Java desktop application based on OpenStreetmap, jXMapKit library.
What I have actually done is displaying map and possibility to center possition by typing X and Y coordinates.
Moreover I would like to display/load on my map some places like: cinema, theater etc. but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Is there any chance to download some list of places from any website and display it on my app?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). For downloading specific POIs you need to know their key-value-pairs. For cinemas this is would be [amenity=cinema](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dcinema). Also take a look at [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). This is a webfrontend for Overpass API and allows you to play around with your queries and to visualize the results.